Quartz Scheduler - Handling changed jobs when NEW code base is deployed LIVE
When we deploy a new cluster running quartz, the old cluster is still running until everything checks out with the new code.
Running the two code bases simultaneously run into a few possible problems when existing jobs are changed or a job is created (new class) within Quartz.  This is my best guess of what to do based on reading the documentation, coding a few examples, and looking on stackoverflow.  Any advice would be appreciate.

For versioning an existing Job, is inserting "minVersion" in the JobData and refiring the Job on the old cluster sufficient?

// New codebase increments minVersion
JobDetail versionedJob = JobBuilder.newJob(ExistingJob.class)
    .withIdentity("existingJob", "defaultGroup")
    .usingJobData("minVersion", 2) // Increased version to 2
    .build();

// All "versioned" jobs have this logic
public class ExistingJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        int minVersion = jobDataMap.getInt("minVersion");

        if (currentVersion < minVersion ) {
            JobExecutionException e = new JobExecutionException("Job execution stopped (incorrect version)");
            e.setRefireImmediately(true);
            throw e;
        }
        ...
    }
}


For a completely new Job (class) in the new code base, is adding misfire handling to the trigger good enough to allow the new cluster to eventually pick it up?

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
  .withIdentity("newJobTrigger", "defaultGroup")
  .startNow()
  .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInSeconds(15)
    .repeatForever()
    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithExistingCount())
  .build();

